# Ошибка при обращении к элементу родительской формы из диалоговой

Tags: c#, winforms

Разрабатывая приложение на c# (WinForms) столкнулся с проблемой:

```
mainForm f = (mainForm)this.Owner;
int w = f.holst.Width;
int h = f.holst.Width;//вот мой код
```

Когда компилятор доходит до второй строчки то появляется ошибка

```
 object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

что это может быть?

Comment: @Кирюха Пирогов это может значить, что у **f** нет поля **holst**. Что в принуипе неудивительно, если это некая форма

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это означает что `this.Owner`  null || this.Owner.holst == null

И при записи

```
mainForm f = (mainForm)this.Owner;
```

`f == null` если `this.Owner` <s>не является классом `mainForm` или его наследником.</s>
если this.Owner == null;

**P.S.**

[[@andreycha](/users/106/andreycha)](/users/106/andreycha), Ваша правда, попутал с Java или 'as' :-)

Comment: И что делать? как еще можно обратиться из диологовой формы к основной?

Comment: Добавте в диалогувую форму ссылку на основную форму и при вызове выставляёте её значение?

Comment: А как значение выставить? я думал вот этой строчкой я их и связываю
mainForm f = (mainForm)this.Owner; //mainForm  - это класс главной формы

Comment: обе формы в одном НеймСпейсе кстати

Comment: Вы диалоговую форму как вызываете (создаёте)? Вот где создаёте/вызываете и выставляйте. Что-то типа:

    ...
    var dialogForm = new MyDialogForm();
    dialogForm.myForm = this;//если вызываете из mainForm
    dialogForm.showModal();
    ...

Comment: спасибо сделал так
<pre>
            editF  dialog = new editF();
            dialog.Owner = this;
</pre>

Comment: "f == null если this.Owner не является классом mainForm или его наследником" неверно. В таком случае будет вызвано исключение. При явном приведении f будет равно null только если Owner == null.

Answer (score 1):

Либо Owner == null, либо свойство holst == null. Посмотрите в отладчике, что именно неинициализировано.